# most efficient way to disable a branch of nested components, ideally O(1) operation

Tags: c#, graph, components, nested

I am working on something that involves execution of many fine-grained commands and handling their side-effects in a synchronous deterministic fashion. I have a potentially large directed cyclic graph of objects, each of which contains a delegate. These objects are grouped into components. Components are hierarchical and can be nested to any depth. The connections between objects can cross component boundaries.

There are two lists (execution buffer, staging buffer) to which some of these objects will be added. As objects in the execution buffer are iterated, their delegates are executed, the result of which determines which (if any) connected objects will be placed in the staging buffer. When iteration is complete, the buffers are swapped, the former execution buffer cleared, and the cycle starts over.

In addition to determining which connected objects to add to the staging buffer, some delegates will result in disabling a component. When disabled, none of the objects within that branch should be processed.

I need the most efficient possible way to specify/identify what components are disabled in order to prevent objects from being processed. The following are options I am aware of...

1. Set a disabled flag on only the parent component of a branch. When considering each object for execution, climb all the way to the root component to see if any are marked disabled... Up to O(n) where n is the depth of the object's owning component. This can be optimized by maintaining a dictionary, so that climbing for any given component need be performed once each cycle.
2. Set a disabled flag on all components in a branch... O(1) for each object because it only needs to check if its owner has its disabled flag set. But O(n) to mark a branch as disabled where n is the number of components in branch.
3. Assign each component a pair of [Farey fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) to represent a [nested interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals), and maintain global record of intervals that are disabled. When considering each object for execution, check if its owning component's interval falls within one of the disabled intervals. Up to O(n) for each object where n is the number of components disabled. This can also be optimized by maintaining a dictionary, so that checking the intervals of any given component need be performed once each cycle. I'm not sure about the scalability of this. How large/deeply nested can a branch become before the fractions start running out of decimal points?
4. Perform some sort of pointer magic so that all components in a branch share a disabled flag.

---

Edit:
A branch of components can be disabled explicitly and/or implicitly. Explicit means that a branch has been marked as disabled. Implicit means a branch is considered disabled because an ancestor branch in the component hierarchy is marked as disabled. If a given branch ***C*** is explicitly disabled and an ancestor branch ***A*** is also disabled, re-enabling ***A*** should not result in ***C*** being enabled. With that in mind I don't see how option 4 could work with a pointer or shared reference. I thought about having two flags, one for an explicit setting and one for implicit. An explicit flag for one component could be used as the implicit flag for child components. But that only lets me disable the immediate child components.

Comment: Did you actually mean 'acyclic' ?

Comment: Did I get the terminology wrong? Objects have inputs and outputs, but no two will have parallel/two-way connections. Object A connects to B connects to C connects to A). I think that is cyclic. But the components in which objects are grouped are hierarchical and don't have any recursive aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 sounds very possible.  All you need is a reference type, I'll call it `FlagHolder`:

```
class FlagHolder
{
    public bool IsDisabled;
}
```

Then create only one `FlagHolder` per group that will be disabled as a unit, and pass it to all the individual objects.

Comment: I added a clarification on why I can't see how option 4 would work. There would need to be a way to combine the results of the flags for a component and all ancestor components. Maybe it would be possible to do it in an efficient manner by storing the flags in a BitArray and performing an Or on a subset of bits... turns out that is a O(n) operation for the number of bits.

Comment: @spruce: depends on how many flags you need... You can OR together 64 bits at once with `ulong flags; bool or_result = (flags != 0);`

Comment: A branch could become more that 64 levels deep and/or have more than 64 children. Maybe some sort of a bit matrix. It seems the bit twiddling for that is a little beyond me. For now I think I will go with option 1 and a dictionary to store what components have been visited in a given cycle. Should I create a "self-answer" or wait to see if others have any input? Thanks.